# Is it possible to use the End of String "$" as a regex capture group?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a comma delimited string whose fields are enclosed in double quotes that looks like the following and would like to split the text using Perl and regex.

I got the first 2 regex capture groups from the Second Edition Perl Cookbook and I tried to modify the regex to capture NULL values at the start of the line, in between and at the end.

There should be 2 NULL values at the end but I am only getting 1 because I am using a look-behind to check if there is a preceding comma.

Is it possible to get a 5th capture group patterned as ,\s*($) ( comma + maybe some whitespace + End of line ) but only getting the End of Line?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = qq(,,," test ",ing,,"hello "", world","some "","" text w/ comma",,,end_test,,);
my @colArr;

while ( $text =~ /([^",]+)|"((?:[^"]|"")*)"|(?<=^)([,])|(?<=[,])([,])/gx ) {

    my $field = '';

    if ( defined $1 ) {
        $field = $1;
    }
    elsif ( defined $2  ) {
        ( $field = $2 ) =~ s/""/"/g;
    }

    # For $3 and 4, comma will be captured but should be treated as NULL
    # Hoping to capture End of line as $5 where exists a comma behind it

    push @colArr, $field;

}

push @colArr, '' if ( $text =~ /[,]$/ or $text eq '' ); # New: Capture final trailing NULL value

for ( my $i = 0; $i < @colArr; $i++ ) {
    print "[$i]\t: $colArr[$i]\n";
}

=pod
Expected:
[0]     :
[1]     :
[2]     :
[3]     :  test
[4]     : ing
[5]     :
[6]     : hello ", world
[7]     : some "," text w/ comma
[8]     :
[9]     :
[10]    : end_test
[11]    :
[12]    :

Actual:
[0]     :
[1]     :
[2]     :
[3]     :  test
[4]     : ing
[5]     :
[6]     : hello ", world
[7]     : some "," text w/ comma
[8]     :
[9]     :
[10]    : end_test
[11]    :
=cut
```

Do let me know if anyone has better ideas on how to do this.
Also, I can't install CPAN modules due to user restrictions.

Comment: Is this coming from a CSV file? Isn't there a perl module for parsing it, so you don't have to roll your own regexp?

Comment: `$` matches the end of the line, but it's a zero-length assertion so nothing will be in the capture group.

Comment: Hi, @Barmar. Thanks for the reply. Do you know any core Perl modules that would parse this as expected above? And yes this could come from a CSV file.

Comment: How about the `Text::CSV` module? It's the first hit from googling "perl csv module.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think the example is in the `$text` variable in the code.

Comment: @Barmar I see... thx.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for the suggestion. I did consider Text::CSV but I am unable to use it as it is a CPAN module and due to restrictions I won't be able to install it.

Comment: Parsing CSV with regular expressions is tricky, it's hard to deal with escaping and quoting. And why did you ask for a module recommendation if you're not allowed to use them? Or is it only CPAN that's restricted? Where else does one find perl modules?

Comment: Anyway, you can google as well as I can.

Comment: @Barmar  They asked for a "core" module ... and there's none such as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I may have solved my own problem. I just added the following "hack" after the while loop. 

push @colArr, '' if ( $text =~ /[,]$/ or $text eq '' ); # New: Capture final trailing NULL value

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for taking up your time but I think I solved my own problem below by adding an additional push after the while loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = qq(,,," test ",ing,,"hello "", world","some "","" text w/ comma",,,end_test,,);
my @colArr;

while ( $text =~ /([^",]+)|"((?:[^"]|"")*)"|(?<=^)([,])|(?<=[,])([,])/gx ) {

    my $field = '';

    if ( defined $1 ) {
        $field = $1;
    }
    elsif ( defined $2  ) {
        ( $field = $2 ) =~ s/""/"/g;
    }

    # For $3 and 4, comma will be captured but should be treated as NULL
    # Hoping to capture End of line as $5 where exists a comma behind it

    push @colArr, $field;

}

push @colArr, '' if ( $text =~ /[,]$/ or $text eq '' ); # New: Capture final trailing NULL value

for ( my $i = 0; $i < @colArr; $i++ ) {
    print "[$i]\t: $colArr[$i]\n";
}
```